# ng2-datetime - Increase the width of the control

Tags: html, angularjs

How can I make the the width of the datetime field align to my other input fields with class col-sm-9 in Angular 2?

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3">What is the Expiry Date ?</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
   <datetime [timepicker]="false" formControlName="ExpiryDate"></datetime>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Email</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Email">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks